# Division operation between two z3.ArithRef varaibles in Z3py

Tags: python-3.x, z3, z3py

Is there a different method to divide two z3.z3.ArithRef variables in Z3py? Here is my sample code:

```
from z3 import *

X = Int('X')
s = Solver()

def pick(X):
    return Or([X==p for p in [0,1]])

var1 = 2.5
var2 = 6.5

total1 = 0
for i in range(5):
    total1 = total1 + If(X == 1, var1 * ToReal(X), 0)
    
total2 = 0
for i in range(5):
    total2 = total2 + If(X == 0, var2 + ToReal(X), 0)
    
s.add(total1/total2 > 0)

r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print(m)
else:
    print("Solver said: %s" % r)
```

The output after adding the constraint `s.add(total1/total2 > 0)` gives me some extra element: `[X = 2, /0 = [else -> 1]]`. This works fine for multiplication i.e. `s.add(total1*total2 == 0)`.

Why is `/0 = [else -> 1]` added and how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division by zero is undefined in SMT, so Z3 tells you which choice it made. In this case it fixes `(x/0)` to `1`, for any `x`.